# Problem with writing to file in C

Tags: c, io

I'm trying to write some information to a file in C and was never running into a problem before.  However, now it seems to break when writing a variable's contents to file.  Here is what I have.

```
    int i, count = 0;
    FILE *f;
    int _x, _y, _z, _x2, _y2, _z2;

    for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT * WIDTH*3; i+= 3)
    {
        if (buffer1[i/3] < MAGIC_VALUE)
        {
            count++;
        }

        if (buffer2[i/3] < MAGIC_VALUE)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Count = %d\n", count); // prints correctly...
    f = fopen("file.abc", "w");
    fprintf(f, "lots\n of\n text\n");

    fprintf(f, "count: %d\ntext \ntext y\ntext text text", count); // crashes here
    fprintf(f, "\nend");

    fclose(f);
```

Why is this line crashing?  It ends up in dbghook.c at the line that says `_debugger_hook_dummy = 0;`

The crash is occurring when printing `count` to the file, but if I take out that print, it will crash when printing the last statement.  The first one seems to be printing fine, though..

When I print the error, I get "Too many open files"

Comment: OS, compiler, options? No telepaths here.

Comment: What is `buffer1`, `buffer2`, `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH`?

Comment: buffer1/2 are arrays of shorts.  HEIGHT and WIDTH are constant ints.

Comment: Do you check as to whether the file is actually open?

Comment: The file is not open.  Even if I change the name to something obscure that doesn't exist, this will occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st step: replace

```
f = fopen( path, mode );
```

with

```
f = fopen( path, mode );
if( f == NULL ) {
    perror( path );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

Comment: 2nd step: close some files :)

Comment: Very strange, especially since visual studio is the only thing open at the time, besides the program itself.

Comment: Closing files doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Even rebooting the system, nada.

Comment: Too many open files thing not solved, but you helped me narrow down what was going on.  Thanks.

Comment: @user696977 closing files does not mean closing them in other programs.  Your program has too many open files.  Possibly you have a loop somewhere in which you call fopen() and fail to call fclose(), or you are just trying to have too many files open at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As for MSVS2008, all works fine. Of course, the 'for' loop was to be commented since used global variables and defines.

First, you should try to do something like

```
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    int count = 0;
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("file.abc", "w");   
    fprintf(f, "count: %d\n", count);  
    fclose(f);
}
```

and see what happens.

Comment: main should always return an int