# fopen in C(Linux) returns "Too many open files"

Tags: c, linux, fopen

```
static char filename[128] = "trace.txt";

g_file = fopen(filename, "w");
if(NULL == g_file)
{
       printf("Cannot open file %s.error %s\n",filename,strerror(errno));
       exit(1);
}
```

I am trying to open a empty text file named trace.txt in write mode (in my working directory.)
The program is creating an empty file trace.txt in my directory.but the check (NULL == g_file)
is returning true and it is returning error code 24 (Too many open files.).Any idea why this is.This is the first file I am opening in my program.

Surprisingly the code is creating an empty file in my working directory by the name specified.However the check for null file pointer is succeeding for some reason.? :(

Comment: Try running your program under `strace`.

Comment: Maybe you reached some limits, or quotas. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10908462/841108

Comment: [this](https://www.robustperception.io/dealing-with-too-many-open-files) also could be useful resource

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have a file descriptor leak.
If your code keeps opening files, never closing them, you will reach the limit sooner or later, and then `fopen` will fail.

You can check this by printing the file descriptor numbers you get whenever opening a file. If they keep growing, you have a leak.

Answer (score 4):

It is most likely due to your system reaching its maximum allowed open file handles.

You can easily test this by running the following:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.dat bs=16 count=1
```

If you are out of file handles, this should provide the same or similar error.

You can trouble shoot this using some of the following commands:

To see the maximum allowed open files:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

To see the which files are currently open (remember this includes device files, sockets, etc):

```
$ lsof
```

You can also use `lsof` to get a count of open files:

```
$ lsof | wc -l
```

Comment: This was very helpful for me, the first line you shared caused no failures whatsoever, so now I know that it is not a "too many files" problem as the error message would lead me to believe it is.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a similar issue to what you're having, but I'm not entirely sure if it will help you solve the problem. Might be worth a look:

[Problem with writing to file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607533/problem-with-writing-to-file-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Correct, I faced same error message and found that I was trying to close the file in a function but not where it was opened. So I then closed in the function where it was opened, later everything went fine.